# Python kivy app test flight shows blank black screen

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, app-store-connect

I have created an app using python kivy, compiled it to an xcode project using kivy-ios, I have tested the app and it works perfectly on the xcode simulators, I have also tested the app on my iPhone as well as my iPad and it works perfectly. When I archive it to app store connect and test flight it, it shows a blank black screen. Anyone ever face this issue? If so, how can I fix this issue?

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYfHS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.